# Complex function integration using trapezoidal rule in C++

Tags: c++, numerical-integration

```
#include <complex>  
complex<double> integral(complex<double> (*f)(complex<double> x), complex<double> l, complex<double> u, size_t n) {
   complex<double> step = (u - l) / (double)n;
   complex<double> area(0, 0);
   for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      complex<double> inner = l + (i + 0.5) * step;
      area = area + f(inner) / inner * step;
   }
   return area;
}
int main() {
   cout << integral(cos, 0, 2, 100);
   return 0;
}
```

error

```
main.cpp:35:13: error: no matching function for call to 'integral'
main.cpp:24:17: note: candidate function not viable: no overload of 'cos' matching 'complex<double> (*)(complex<double>)' for 1st argument
```

I would like to integrate complex function using trapezoidal method.

The lower and the upper bounds are complex numbers as well.

If I only use `double` (I replace every `complex<double>` to `double`) it is working I am getting the proper solution, but if I use `complex<double>` I get the previously mentioned error code.

Maybe there are issues in my algorithm, I would appreciate if you could highlights me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`integral`'s first parameter type

```
complex<double> (*f)(complex<double> x)
```

is wrong.

The complex form of `std::cos` [takes its parameter by constant reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/cos).

Change your first parameter to this and `std::cos` will be a match.

```
complex<double> (*f)(complex<double> const & x)
//                                   ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, I can run the code but I get a incorrect result. I have just edited my post.

Comment: @taiwan12 your original question was answered. Please don't edit the question to ask a new question.

Comment: @bolov Maybe there are issues in my algorithm, I would appreciate if you could highlights me. This was my last sentence.

Comment: @taiwan12 while I understand that you need to be aware of the site rules. If you want to ask a different question now (about why your algorithm is giving you wrong output) then consider asking a new question.

Comment: @taiwan12 you are being encouraged to push the [Ask Question] button at the top of this page, as you seem to have a new question to ask.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the complex overloads of `std::cos` take their argument by reference.  That makes them incompatible with a function pointer type with the argument by value.

```
template< class T >
complex<T> cos( const complex<T>& z );
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/cos

Instead of chasing a moving target (exact parameter types), I would suggest using an abstraction such as `std::function<complex<double> (complex<double>)>`